# how to dispatch multiple actions in same epic

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using React, Redux, Redux-Observable, rxjs and TypeScript. I have a epic which creates records. I want to dispatch an additional action from the epic.

```
export const createEpic: Epic = (action$) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(ITEMS_CREATE),
    mergeMap((action) => CoreCom.create<{Item: Item}>(
        '/items/index',
        {},
        'Item',
        action.item,
    ).pipe(
        map((response) => itemsCreateSuccess(response.response)),
        catchError(() => of(itemsCreateFailure())),
    )),
);
```

```
export const createSuccesEpic: Epic = (action$) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(ITEMS_CREATE_SUCCESS),
    map(
        () => enqueueSnackbar({
            message: 'Hello World!',
            options: {
                variant: 'success',
            },
        }),
    ),
);
```

The first epic reacts on action `ITEMS_CREATE`. Then it fires a call and gets back a server response. Then the action `ITEMS_CREATE_SUCCESS` is dispatched.
Additionally I want to dispatch an action to show a notification. I ended up with two epics.

Can somebody help me to "merge" this two epics into one? Or is this good as it is?

I wasn't able to dispatch two actions from the same epic.

EDIT:

FYI: the function `itemsCreateSuccess()`, `itemsCreateSuccess()` and `enqueueSnackbar()` are returning something similar to this:

```
export const itemsCreateSuccess = (response: Response): ItemsCreateSuccessAction => ({
    type: ITEMS_CREATE_SUCCESS,
    response,
});
```

they are just returning actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution, in my opinion, has a good point which is the separation of concerns which can bring more flexibility to your code because later you can use this `createSuccesEpic` epic to show those success notifications for different "success actions" (as I do not know the context of your app is up to you to take that in consideration).

To your question about how you can dispatch those two actions from `createEpic` I see a solution using `mergeMap` and `merge` on your second pipe. So your code will look like this:

```js
export const createEpic: Epic = (action$) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(ITEMS_CREATE),
    mergeMap((action) => CoreCom.create<{Item: Item}>(
        '/items/index',
        {},
        'Item',
        action.item,
    ).pipe(
        mergeMap(response => merge(
            of(itemsCreateSuccess(response.response)),
            of(enqueueSnackbar({ ... }))
        )),
        catchError(() => of(itemsCreateFailure())),
    )),
);
```

Comment: thank you. your solution works as expected! however, i will use my solution because of your first argument.